# My information is going through the API to the browser but not appearing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-applications, frontend, backend

I am fetching my information from a API in node.js to a react app and the data is entering the browser but appearing not app

```
import './CSS_PSI.css'
import logout from './logout.ico';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


function Projetos  ()  {


const [post, setpost] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
 fetch("/projeto/all")
    axios.get("/projeto/all").then((res) =>{
      setpost(res);
    });
}, []);

console.log(post);


return (
  <div className="App">
    {post?.length > 0 ? (
      post.map((value, key) => {
        return (
          
          <div className="post">
            <div className="title"> {value.titulo} </div>
            <div className="body">{value.regras}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    ) : (
      <div className="title">Data Loading.. </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
}
 
export default Projetos;
```

[The data is in the broser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MMIj.png)

various types of fetching but it still doesn't work